# WPF TextBlock.IsHitTestVisible doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how this is supposed to work, but from everything I've read it's my understanding that setting the IsHitTestVisible property to false should essentially make that element "invisible" to mouse events, and MSDN states that this property "declares whether this element can possibly be returned as a hit test result".

I have a procedurally generated Grid, each cell contains a Border, and each Border's child is a TextBlock.

This is how I'm creating the cell:

```
var cellBorder = new Border { BorderBrush = Brushes.LightGray, Background = Brushes.WhiteSmoke, BorderThickness = thickness };
var label = new TextBlock { Text = time.ToShortTimeString(), Foreground = Brushes.Tomato, IsHitTestVisible = false };
cellBorder.Child = label;
_grid.Children.Add(cellBorder);
Grid.SetColumn(cellBorder, j);
Grid.SetRow(cellBorder, i);
```

In an DragMove event handler, I want to change background color of the current cell.  This was working fine before I added the TextBlock to the border.  It looks something like this:

```
    void _grid_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var pos = e.GetPosition(_grid);
        var result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(_grid, pos);

        if (result != null)
        {
            var border = result.VisualHit as Border;
            if (border != null)
                border.Background = Brushes.LightYellow;
            else if (result.VisualHit is TextBlock)
                Console.WriteLine("Textblock hit");  // Why is this happening?
        }
    }
```

The TextBlock is getting returned from the hit test.  Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `VisualTreeHelper` does not take `IsHitTestVisible` into account.

If you want to omit the `TextBlock` from the hit test for `VisualTreeHelper` then you should pass [filter callbacks to HitTest()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608753%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!  I guess I'm still confused as to why MSDN says that the property determines whether or not the element "can be returned as a hit test result".  Are they not referring to the HitTest method?

Comment: you're welcome! the attribute is used internally for mouse/touch events, if you add a `Tap` or `Drag` event to the `TextBlock` it will get ignored if `IsHitTestVisible==false`